Using LINQ to convert a listed model into another listed model
I am trying to convert one model into another model that is a slightly different format. I was thinking I could do this in one line without a foreach by using LINQ however I keep running into an error about conversion of types. Here is my code:
                    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>().AddRange<Recipient>(email.To.Select(contact => new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                        },
                    }));

The models are:
    public class CreateEmail
{
    [ModelBinder(Name = "from")]
    [Required]
    public required Contact From { get; set; }
    
    [ModelBinder(Name = "to")]
    public List<Contact>? To { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();

    [ModelBinder(Name = "cc")]
    public List<Contact>? Cc { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();

    [ModelBinder(Name = "bcc")]
    public List<Contact>? Bcc { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(Name = "subject")]
    [Required]
    public required string Subject { get; set; } = "";

    [ModelBinder(Name = "body")]
    [Required]
    public required string Body { get; set; } = "";

    public List<FileAttachment>? FileAttachments { get; set; } = new List<FileAttachment>();
}

    public class Contact
{
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required]
    public required string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    
    public string? Name {get; set;}
}

The error I am running into is :
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Graph.Models.Recipient>' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan<Microsoft.Graph.Models.Recipient>'CS1503

I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong here as it seemed straight forward. I am looping through my email model and creating a new ms graph recipient object which is returning to the range. Any help would be appreciated!

Show the code for the classes, we can't guess what they look like.

Added the CreateEmail model.

Hi @Qiuzman, what is the type of ToRecipients ?

When I hover over it , it is List? Message.ToRecipients { get; set; }

I am using MS Graph API to send emails.

which version of graph api, do you have link to the documentation? There might be a static function so you could add recipients-- not just by setting.

To correctly convert the list from your CreateEmail model to the format expected by the MS Graph API. Change your code to below:
ToRecipients = email.To?.Select(contact => new Recipient
{
    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
    {
        Address = contact.EmailAddress,
        Name = contact.Name
    }
}).ToList();


The code snippet isn't very clear but from looking at the error message, the property ToRecipients is not a type derived from IEnumerable.
